# Assign value to gridview textbox using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am new to jquery and would like to know how to assign a value into a gridview textbox using jquery. I would like to do something similar to the following:

document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').value;

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specifically are you having trouble with? If you haven't tried anything yet, take a look at the jQuery API Documentation, specifically the `val()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function and [id selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').val());
```